# Saving color in Mysettingscolor and returning

Tags: vb.net, colors, save

I am coding on vb.net. I have a program that the user select a color from a picture and the color is stored to compare with another pixel from the picture, then when the colors match it make a mark in the picture. Then I save the color in my.settings.myColor. When the user select the color, it returns as "Color[A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]", until here works totally fine. The problem is, when I close the program and reopen, it does not return like "Color[A=255, R=255, G=255, B=255]", it returns like this Color[White]. So, when I do to compare the colors to find some matching colors, it does not find anything. I am assuming it is because, it is returning different, am I right?

```
Dim cor As Color = My.Settings.Mycolor
```

```
Private Sub FrmBitmaps_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
colour = My.Settings.Mycolor

cmdColorPicker.BackColor = My.Settings.Mycolor
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you should store the individual values for Alpha, Red, Green and Blue as integers. Then on startup, simply use `Color color1 = Color.FromArgb(A, R, G, B)`

Comment: @preciousbetine But, how can I store each value from a color? Thanks for the advice

Comment: @preciousbetine oh..I found it. THank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I created a setting in the application properties on the settings tab. It looks like this.

[image]

To get the Type scroll down to Browse in the drop down and find System.Drawing.Color. The scope is set to User so it can be edited.

To set the setting

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    My.Settings.TestColor = Color.FromArgb(255, 237, 28, 36)
End Sub
```

Then I closed the application and re-openned it and clicked Button 2.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim MyRetrievedColor = My.Settings.TestColor
    TextBox1.BackColor = MyRetrievedColor
End Sub
```